# how to stop CSE dont repeat CSE

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 80
int main()
{
   FILE* fp = fopen("fp.txt" ,"r");
   char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
   if(fp!=NULL)
    {
         while (!feof(fp))
            {
                fscanf(fp ,"%s",buf);
                  printf("Read line: %s\n" ,buf);\
                  printf("\n");
            }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
//need create fp file 
    UW
    CSE
```

how to stop CSE dont repeat CSE again. Can  you use condition if-else do-while etc.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: What is a CSE that repeats CSE?

Comment: You want to stop CSE not repeating CSE again? I.e. you want it to repeat CSE another time?

Comment: Please provide sample input, current output, desired output and explain the difference. Also please include in your output the values returned by fscanf().

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) The function `feof` does not do what many beginners imagine.

The reason why you repeat the input `CSE`, is because after you read *beyond* the end of the file, that data remains in the buffer.

I advise you to change the loop to

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%79s", buf) == 1) {
    printf("Read line: %s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Minor point on code formatting: the space character is usually typed *after* a comma, not before it.